# Changing layer name in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, layers, geoserver-manager

I install the GeoServer 2.18 in Windows Server 2012 r2, and with tomcat 9, JRE 1.8.
it works fine.
but I cannot change the layer title/name.
when I want to change the name, and I will get the error message

> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

I find some way to try to fix, like use the Xmax=512M,

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please share the full stack trace, from the logs.

Comment: Works for me with GeoServer 2.18 on Windows 10. I could change the names and titles of the demo layers without errors. What browser do you have on  Windows Server 2012?

Comment: i use the chrome

Comment: ok , i will try to download this log  file .

Answer (score 1):

Run the startup.bat file with Run as administrator then you can change the layers name easily.

Answer (score 0):

In the final, I change the authority of webapp/geoserver folder.
It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure the Tomcat Application is run with Administrator privilege, I solve this problem by manually run the tomcat services